# Fine Uploader Scaling renderImageToCanvas

Tags: canvas, scaling, fine-uploader

I am using S3 Fine Uploader's scaling feature to upload two scaled images without the original. I have written my own code under the renderImageToCanvas function to customize the images as follows:

Scaled Image 1: A max size 300px which I crop into a 300x300 square

Scaled Image 2: A max size 800px which I create a high quality image of

Under the renderImageToCanvas function, what I'd like to do is to check  options.width (or pass through maxWidth) to determine what to do with each scaled image e.g. something like this:

```
if(options.width == 300)
{

//Crop image into 300x300px square

}else{

//high quality resize to maxWidth 800

}
```

However, options.width is null the first time the renderImageToCanvas function is called so the above does not work. Is there a simple way of identifying a scaled image based on it's size within the renderImageToCanvas function so I can achieve the above?

Comment: What is the "renderImageToCanvas" function? Is this an internal method? If so, your best bet is to delete this question and either open up a pull request against fine Uploader, or a feature request to ask for whatever functionality you are looking for to be added to the library.

Comment: The function is within s3.fine-uploader.js I understand it is part of a 3rd party library Mega pixel image. I located this through issue #1525 where other people have done high quality resizing. If necessary I will go ahead with a feature/pull request but all I'm after urgently is a way to customize each scaled image. Is there any other simple way I can do this? As mentioned I've done all the cropping/resizing and just need to plug it in. Many thanks.

Comment: Since this is related to an existing open feature request, let's deal with it there